# How to abort request like IIS request Abort in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, httpresponse, httpcontext

I just want to abort request like IIS request abort. I am not sure how can I do it in C# but need some expert to do it.

Can we abort user request in `IHttpModule`? I can do `response.end()` but couldn't see the message like: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Here is my code to end request in `IHttpModule`. If it's possible I want to abort user's request.

```
private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Result is empty screen with this code. Expected result is `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Response.End()` is closing the connection, its abort on your side, and on client side is just stops the loading - close the connection - Not leave it open until gets time out -

So its normal what you get - not a time out

Comment: Thanks, i understand the situation. Also we can redirect via HttpContext.Current.Response.Statuscode but non of these giving ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT . I guess i will create my own message right? :)

Comment: @Hallowen You may send this one -> 504 Gateway Timeout.